# function object that converts string to uppercase

Tags: c++, string, functor, uppercase

I would like to make a function object that converts a string letters to uppercase so that I can pass that functor to `transform()`  - `transform(string.begin(), string.end(), string.begin(), stringToUp());` . I know I can do it otherway, it is just an exercise. Here is my code that works, but my question is why does it work since I pass `stringToUp` to `transform` without any parameters?

```
class stringToUp{

public:

    int operator()(int ex) {
        return toupper(ex);  // ?? 
    }
};

int main(){

string k("toupper");

    transform(k.begin(), k.end(), k.begin(), stringToUp());
}
```

Comment: "why does it work since I pass stringToUp to transform without any parameters?" `std::transform` does this, not you.

Comment: `std::transform()` calls the `operator()` of the object you pass.    But why not pass `std::toupper` to `std::transform()`?

Comment: @Peter as I said, it is just an exercise to understand how functors work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringToUp` is a class. You can have an object that is a `stringToUp`:

```
int main() {
    stringToUp toUp;
    return 0;
}
```

It has an `operator()`, so you can use objects of type `stringToUp` like functions

```
int main() {
    stringToUp toUp;
    char x = toUp('x');
    return 0;
}
```

When you are writing a template, functions and function objects look the same:

```
template<typename Functor>
void transform(int& out, int in, Functor functor) {
   out = functor(in);
}

int main() {
    stringToUp toUp;
    char x, y;
    transform(x, 'x', toUp); // like "x = toUp('x');"
    transform(x, 'x', std::toupper); // like "y = std::toupper('y');"
    return 0;
}
```